# How to get Facebook user detail from Access Token using Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm really struggling to understand what's happening here. I can get a Users details fine  in the OpenGraph tester or just hitting the URL https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=VALID_TOKEN or using file_get_contents, but when trying the Codeigniter Facebook Library I get error *"An active access token must be used..."* and if I just try a CURL GET I get no output. I know the access_token is valid so why aren't they working? The overall objective is to get an access_token from iOS App and use this to do a Like via the web server using og.likes.

**My test function:**

```
function me_test(){
    $access_token = "VALID_TOKEN";
    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=';
    $url_full = $url.$access_token;

    $result = file_get_contents($url_full);
    echo $result;

    // Try Codeigniter Facebook Library
    try {
        $user = $this->facebook->api('/me?access_token='.$access_token);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print_r($e);
    }

    // Codeigniter CURL Library
    $this->load->library('curl');  
    echo $this->curl->simple_get($url_full);
    $info =  $this->curl->info;
    print_r($info);

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `access_token` in `$access_token` is actually the one you are testing against the OG tester? I don't this this has anything to do with CI.

Comment: @ifaour I just discovered something which might help. I re-ran my test function and this time the CI Library function worked and the file_get_contents gave an error. If I just hit the URL https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=VALID_TOKEN I get message "..user logged out...". Is there some sort of caching or sesssion problem? The CI Library call should give an error as the token is now expired.

Comment: The Facebook SDK should work fine. You are saying that you are receiving this access token from a mobile app, then maybe you are logging the user out there and hence the `access_token` is becoming invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this issue and find the alternate way to get userdata. You can try this

```
function me_test(){
    $userId = $this->facebook->getUser(); //This will return the current user id

    // Try Codeigniter Facebook Library
    try {
        $user = $this->facebook->api('/'.$userId);
        //When you pass the userid you dont need to provide access token
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print_r($e);
    }    
}
```